# Read file content in WORKSPACE

Tags: bazel, starlark

I'm using `container_pull` in my WORKSPACE file. (It's part of [bazel docker rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker))
Here is what it looks like:

```py
container_pull(
    name = "base-image",
    registry = "registry:9999",
    repository = "base-image",
    digest = "sha256:e6f44554a270025c578c0f91160d809735c2589baae80bafcdeebefb0c0b04b6",
    tag = "1.1.0"
)
```

Howeve, there is a file containing the version of `base-image`, and I want it to be read from that file, instead of hardcoding in WORKSPACE.
How can I read a file content in WORKSPACE?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to read a file from the workspace file. The `container_pull` rule would have to add support for reading from a file.

A workaround is to put the file that contains the information into `.bzl` format, and load that from the workspace file.

Something like this:

`versions.bzl`:

```
BASE_IMAGE_VERSION = "1.1.0"
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("//:versions.bzl", "BASE_IMAGE_VERSION")

container_pull(
    name = "base-image",
    registry = "registry:9999",
    repository = "base-image",
    digest = "sha256:e6f44554a270025c578c0f91160d809735c2589baae80bafcdeebefb0c0b04b6",
    tag = BASE_IMAGE_VERSION,
)
```

Bazel does a similar thing in its own workspace file:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/669a1a2634bdf267f890cf88833c9712d4e75016/WORKSPACE#L589